# Not able to mount jenkins volume to Windows folder.Empty folder in container when mounting a host directory

Tags: docker

Empty folder in container when mounting a host directory.

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 5000:5000 -v C:/Users/***/Desktop/ABC:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts`

I'm using above command to mount `jenkins_home` directory to local directory but it silently failing.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings 
And Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in Public folder.
it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure under Docker `Settings > Resources > FILE SHARING`,
The host path exists in this list, else you should add it

In your example, you should check `C:/Users/***/Desktop/ABC`